# Android: How To Start An Activity When Screen Locked

Tags: android, locking, screen

I'm developing a VOIP liked app and I want to receive a call when my phone is screen locked.
Also, if I set the lock pattern for my phone, I want to show the activity before I make the unlock pattern. Could you please help to give me any advice or example?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What is with the random paragraph at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will open screen lock

```
Window wind;
        wind = this.getWindow();
        wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        wind.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Comment: Thanks for your rapidly reply, but it seems not work. I start the call activity from a service, then I add the flags in Activity.onStart() callback. But seems Android immediately call Activity.onResume(), Activity.onPause(), Android.onStop() after call Activity.onStart(). Do I miss anthing? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for it's still not work. Do I miss any permission? For now I add permission DISABLE_KEYGUARD and WAKE_LOCK. Are they enough? Thanks very much.

Comment: I am using same code but i am started Activity from Broadcast receiver, it is working for me

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I 'm following your indication and it do resolve my problem, also as below:

```
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);  
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

But the call sequence of Activity callback is very strange, it will call onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), then recall onStart(), onPause() suddenly. And because I finish() the Activity when onPause(), so I incorrectly believe the Activity is nevery resumed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I know that this is 3 years late, but this still worked for me now! Thanks!